# cannot find js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have stucture code like this:

[image]

I try to load javascript into php file like this:

[image]

But i have an error like this:
[image]

This is my html :
[image]

And this is another javascript:

[image]

And i try to copy paste the link, and i got an error 404 not found. How can i fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: Are you serving these files from localhost? We need context of your server.

Comment: Assuming that you have the files in the right place, you may be getting a 404 from your server because the server doesn't have permission to access these files. Check your permissions.

Comment: where is the file that contains the script links? is it index.php?

Comment: Show your HTML, at least.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the files in correct location?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi updated! :)

Comment: @Sinistralis no, i just want to add the folder of js to my page html

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: Most probably you didn't add Fusionchart library file @user3505775

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton i don't know to change permission access file, can you help me how to change the permission?

Comment: My guess is you are not serving these libraries from your server, you are trying to access them via filepath which isn't going to work. They need served from your server.

Comment: @Bindrid no, the folder direction is added because i use php codeigniter framework

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev please check the updated, thanks.

Comment: **"And this is another JavaScript"**. How do you refer this "another" JS in your HTML? I do not see it at all. How do you use it?

Comment: @VajiraLasantha yes, i have the file in the js folder, do you need the subfolder capture?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi can you help me, how to add the library, because i very beginner in codeigniter. thanks.

Comment: @Sinistralis actually, i don't want to access my js file using filepath, but the codeigniter change the direction using pathfile. If i want to access it using pathfile, can you tell me how to change configuration, so i can using filepath?

Comment: you need to check the path of your JS file.. If your js file is in root folder you might try like this.
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the another javascript is javascript code in the html, please check the updated post, i have post another javascript, thanks.

Comment: Ok, let me phrase my question a different way. What is your current public directory for your server? Most frameworks serve static contant via ROOT_URL/public or ROOT_URL/assets.

Comment: unless you use the full address, paths are relative to the page.  If your page is in the application folder you will need to add ../ to go up a level.

Comment: bro using screenshots 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Permissions**

When the host is correct, and the file is in the right place, and you have no other networking problems, you may sometimes still get a 404 because of bad file permissions. If a server does not have permission to access a file, it may send out a 404 error in response. The reason why some "Not Authorized" error is not given *instead*, is that this would reveal more information about the files than you, the owner of the server, may intend. The way to respond to requests for privileged files without revealing whether or not they exist is to give a 404.

On Windows, you can view and change the permissions from the File Explorer by right-clicking on the file or folder, then going to Properties -> Security -> Edit. For more information, [see the notes on permissions on Microsoft's site.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344.aspx)

**File Types**

Besides permissions, a server must also be configured to serve the type of file you are accessing. If files with different extensions are served, but `.js` files are not, check the configuration of your server to make sure that `.js` files aren't blacklisted (or not whitelisted, as the case may be).

**Directory Location**

You should also verify that the files are actually stored in the top-most directory of the web server *if* that's how you are accessing them. If they aren't, you may need to prefix the path with the path from the webserver root to your application directory. E.g., instead of `fusioncharts/...`, you may need `/path/to/fusioncharts/...` or `../../path/to/fusioncharts`.

**Other Considerations**

In your particular case, you should also verify that the files inside the `fusioncharts` folder are actually structured the way you think. (E.g., is there really a `js/[insert name here].js` file inside the `fusioncharts` folder?

If none of that solves your problem, try to take something that *is* working and gradually make it more and more similar to the files that aren't working. By figuring out at which point you go from a working setup to a not working setup, you may discover the problem.

Comment: i have changed my folder access, but nothing is changed, the error still appeared in console firebug.

Comment: @user3505775 See my edit. Also make sure that the *server* has access to the files. To test to see if permissions are the problem, you might temporarily make them readable/executable by every user, and then see if the problem goes away. If it doesn't, you know it's something besides that. Last, you might also want to make sure that your server is configured to serve `.js` files. If it isn't, that could also give a 404.

Comment: your ansers is right. I just wrong not using filepath using http. The file path must using like this : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/NewTesting/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>

Comment: You don't need the domain in there. If you include "localhost" in the path, then it will not work when accessed from outside your machine. Instead, you can just put `/NewTesting/fusioncharts/...`.

Comment: @user3505775 why not use codeigniter base_url() function?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to a file with path:  /ui/new-file.js

then,

1.In html file include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/new-file.js"></script>
```

2.In server.js or app.js whichever you have, include

```
app.get('/ui/new-file.js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'login-file.js'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using codeigniter, you can use `base_url()` function to include JS files in your codeignitor view template file.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

codeigniter default view template is called `welcome_message.php` and this file is located in application/view folder.

This is how I include js files in my codeigniter projects. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In the html you can write *script**  in the head or in the body, but **not** in your file js, delete this in fusionCharts.js

```
<script type=text/javascript>
```

In fusionCharts.js write only the function without the script

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing locally, try clearing your cache.

Google Chrome likes to use the cached JavaScript files instead of the real ones.

Clearing your cache should resolve the issue.