# JavaScript Method not Running

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get this method to run, but I couldn't get it to work. It was working when I kept my JavaScript methods within the HTML, but now that I moved the JavaScript into an external file, it is not doing anything:

This is my html:

```
<head>
    <title>TheNewTao Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="greetings()">
```

I want the method `greetings()` to run as soon as the page is loaded. This is my `script.js` file

```
function greetings() {
  var name = prompt('Hello, what is your name');
  document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'Welcome to the web ' + name;
}
```

All files are in the same folder. Does anyone know why it is not working?

Comment: Does the network tab show the JS file being loaded correctly? BTW, why are you using `innerHTML` to set the text content of an element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Unless you answer the question of whether the network tab shows the JS file being downloaded correctly or not, the question is in danger of being close-voted for not providing the information necessary to give a solution. If you don't know what devtools is or how to view its network tab, then please delete the question, [go study how to do that](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), then repost if you still have problems.

Comment: Have you tried putting your JS on the page between `script` tags to cancel out any weird path issues?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388726/cannot-find-js-file.

Comment: @cchambers He already said the code was working when inside the HTML.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Is it possible that the HTML isn't formatted correctly? The provided HTML is missing `html` and closing `body` tags.

Comment: BTW, the `type="text/javascript"` is unnecessary (as is `type="text/css"`).

Comment: I'm strongly suspecting you don't understand Chrome devtools or the console, because if you did you would have reported a console message such as `"Uncaught ReferenceError: greetings is not defined"`. Do you know what devtools and the console is?

Answer (score 2):

If both files are in the same directory change:

```
<script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What does the `./` do/

Comment: Starting a path with a dot means to reference things _relatively_. So if your `index.html` is at the same location as `script.js` using `./` basically means to look in same directory.

Comment: But it will look in the same directory anyway without the `./`.

Comment: The `./` is just a good practice to be explicit and not depend on a default

Comment: I changed it and still nothing

Comment: @Pablo did you check using a tool like chrome's dev-tools that the file was downloaded properly?

Comment: It seems only my css and HTML file were downloaded, how can I make are the js file is downloaded as well?

Comment: Did you get a 404? Perhaps your `script.js` is not in the correct location?

Comment: @Pablo You can see what HTTP response you're receiving by clicking on the file and looking at the "Headers" tab in chrome: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/18rG7w6.png).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the forward slash in your script src path.  Remove the '/'

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've tested this out in plunkr and it seems to work...

https://plnkr.co/edit/MlkxUF7R31jmBwgWqTE7

My guess is your script.js file is located somewhere else

Comment: Odd where is your script.js file located Pablo?

Comment: Same folder as my HTML and css